# Prevent duplicate cron jobs running

Tags: cron, scheduling

I have scheduled a cron job to run every minute but sometimes the script takes more than a minute to finish and I don't want the jobs to start "stacking up" over each other. I guess this is a concurrency problem - i.e. the script execution needs to be mutually exclusive.

To solve the problem I made the script look for the existence of a particular file ("*lockfile.txt*") and exit if it exists or `touch` it if it doesn't. But this is a pretty lousy semaphore! Is there a best practice that I should know about? Should I have written a daemon instead?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

There are a couple of programs that automate this feature, take away the annoyance and potential bugs from doing this yourself, and avoid the stale lock problem by using flock behind the scenes, too (which is a risk if you're just using touch).  I've used `lockrun` and `lckdo` in the past, but now there's `flock`(1) (in newish versions of util-linux) which is great.  It's really easy to use:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/fcj.lockfile /usr/local/bin/frequent_cron_job
```

Comment: lckdo is going to be removed from moreutils, now that flock(1) is in util-linux. And that package is basically mandatory in Linux systems, so you should be able to rely on it's presence. For usage, look below.

Comment: Yeah, flock is now my preferred option.  I'll even update my answer to suit.

Comment: Does anyone know the difference between `flock -n file command` and `flock -n file -c command` ?

Comment: @Nanne, I'd have to check the code to be sure, but my educated guess is that `-c` runs the specified command through a shell (as per the manpage), while the "bare" (non-`-c`) form just `exec`s the command given.  Putting something through the shell allows you to do shell-like things (such as running multiple commands separated with `;` or `&&`), but also opens you up to shell expansion attacks if you're using untrusted input.

Comment: What is the minutely option?

Comment: It was an argument to the (hypothetical) `frequent_cron_job` command that tried to show it was being run every minute.  I've removed it since it added nothing useful, and caused confusion (yours, if nobody else's over the years).

Comment: Damn, I just spent an hour building out a bash script that does exactly what `flock` does automatically. Ah well, learned a thing or two. ;) For anybody interested, here's the article I went through and it does a good job teaching you basic fundamentals of what `flock`, no doubt, is doing (but likely better): https://bencane.com/2015/09/22/preventing-duplicate-cron-job-executions/

Answer (score 31):

Best way in shell is to use [flock(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)

```
(
  flock -x -w 5 99
  ## Do your stuff here
) 99>/path/to/my.lock
```

Comment: I can't not upvote a tricky use of fd redirection.  It's just too arcanely awesome.

Comment: Doesn't parse for me in Bash or ZSH, need to eliminate the space between `99` and `>` so it is `99> /...`

Comment: @Kyle Yup, correct! Fixed!

@womble Haha, agreed :)

Comment: This is brilliant simplicity.

Comment: beautiful!  and @wombie, it's documented in flock's man page

Comment: @Javier: Doesn't mean it's not tricky and arcane, just that it's *documented*, tricky, and arcane.

Comment: what would happen if you restart while this is running or get the process killed somehow ? Would it be locked forever then ?

Comment: I understand this structure creates an exclusive lock but I don't understand the mechanics of how this is accomplished. What is the function of the '99' in this answer? Anyone care to explain this please? Thanks!

Comment: @JMoons 99 is just an arbitrary fd number that's high enough it likely isn't already being used by the shell.  The shell opens it when executing the subshell (parentheses).  Then when it uses fork() to spawn the child process (including 'flock'), the fd remains open.  Finally, the '99' parameter as the last argument to 'flock' tells the flock program to blindly use the 99 fd for the lock file.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently recent bash: ( flock -x -w ${FD}; do stuff ) {FD}>/path/to/my.lock

Comment: @Asciiom `flock` lets you pass a file number instead of a file name or directory name. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify that you want a file named `99`, if you pass `99`, it automatically interprets it as file with no name with the number 99. Then bash lets you redirect the output of file number 99 to a particular file name using `99>/path/to/my.lock`.

Answer (score 26):

Actually, `flock -n` may be used instead of `lckdo`*, so you will be using code from kernel developers.

Building on [womble's example](https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running/82863#82863), you would write something like:

```
* * * * * flock -n /some/lockfile command_to_run_every_minute
```

BTW, looking at the code, all of `flock`, `lockrun`, and `lckdo` do the exact same thing, so it's just a matter of which is most readily available to you.

Answer (score 6):

Now that systemd is out, there is another scheduling mechanism on Linux systems:

### A `systemd.timer`

In `/etc/systemd/system/myjob.service` or `~/.config/systemd/user/myjob.service`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myjob
```

In `/etc/systemd/system/myjob.timer` or `~/.config/systemd/user/myjob.timer`:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

If the service unit is already activating when the timer next activates, then another instance of the service will *not* be started.

An alternative, which starts the job once at boot and one minute after each run is finished:

```
[Timer]
OnBootSec=1m
OnUnitInactiveSec=1m 

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Answer (score 4):

You havent specified if you want the script to wait for the previous run to complete or not. By "I don't want the jobs to start "stacking up" over each other", I guess you are implying that you want the script to exit if already running,

So, if you don want to depend on lckdo or similar, you can do this:

```
PIDFILE=/tmp/`basename $0`.pid

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
  if ps -p `cat $PIDFILE` > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "$0 already running!"
      exit
  fi
fi
echo $$ > $PIDFILE

trap 'rm -f "$PIDFILE" >/dev/null 2>&1' EXIT HUP KILL INT QUIT TERM

# do the work
```

Comment: Thanks your example is helpful - I do want the script to exit if already running. Thanks for mentioning *ickdo* - it seems to do the trick.

Comment: FWIW: I like this solution because it can be included in a script, so the locking works regardless of how the script is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lock file. Create this file when the script starts and delete it when it finishes. The script, before it runs its main routine, should check if the lock file exists and proceed accordingly.

Lockfiles are used by initscripts and by many other applications and utilities in Unix systems.

Comment: this is the *only* way I've ever seen it implemented, personally. I use on as per the maintainer's suggestion as a mirror for an OSS project

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [run-one](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/run-one.1.html) command - much simpler than dealing with the locks. From the docs:

**run-one** is a wrapper script that runs no more than one unique instance of some command with a unique set of arguments. This is often useful with cronjobs, when you want no more than one copy running at a time.

**run-this-one** is exactly like run-one, except that it will use pgrep and kill to find and kill any running processes owned by the user
and matching the target commands and arguments. Note that run-this-one will block while trying to kill matching processes, until all matching
processes are dead.

**run-one-constantly** operates exactly like run-one except that  it
respawns "COMMAND [ARGS]" any time COMMAND exits (zero or non-zero).

**keep-one-running** is an alias for run-one-constantly.

**run-one-until-success** operates exactly like run-one-constantly except
that it respawns "COMMAND [ARGS]" until COMMAND exits successfully (ie,
exits zero).

**run-one-until-failure** operates exactly like run-one-constantly except
that it respawns "COMMAND [ARGS]" until COMMAND exits with failure (ie,
exits non-zero).

Answer (score 1):

This might also be a sign that you're doing the wrong thing. If your jobs run that closely and that frequently, maybe you should consider de-cronning it and making it a daemon-style program.

Comment: I heartily disagree with this.  If you have something that needs to run periodically, making it a daemon is a "sledgehammer for a nut" solution.  Using a lockfile to prevent accidents is a perfectly reasonable solution I've never had a problem using.

Comment: @womble I agree; but I like smashing nuts with sledgehammers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your cron daemon shouldn't be invoking jobs if previous instances of them are still running. I'm the developer of one cron daemon [dcron](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html), and we specifically try to prevent that. I don't know how Vixie cron or other daemons handle this.

Comment: anyone knows how other crons handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one jar to solve such issue like duplicate crons are running could be java or shell cron. Just pass cron name in Duplicates.CloseSessions("Demo.jar") this will search and kill existng pid for this cron except current. I have implemented method to do this stuff. String proname=ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
                String pid=proname.split("@")[0];
                System.out.println("Current PID:"+pid);

```
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c"," ps aux | grep "+cronname+" | awk '{print $2}' "});

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String s = null;
            String killid="";

            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null ) {                                        
                if(s.equals(pid)==false)
                {
                    killid=killid+s+" ";    
                }
            }
```

And then kill killid string with again shell command

Comment: I don't think this is really answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

@Philip Reynolds answer will start executing the code after the 5s wait time anyways without getting the lock.
Following [Flock doesn't seem to be working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388026/flock-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) I modified @Philip Reynolds answer to

```
(
  flock -w 5 -x 99 || exit 1
  ## Do your stuff here
) 99>/path/to/my.lock
```

so that the code would never be executed simultaniously.
Instead after the 5 sec wait the process will exit with 1 if it did not get the lock by then.