# how to make crontab that work effective?

Tags: cron, fedora

and I am newbie for linux, I am sorry if this question is so dumb.
I would like to know to create crontab properly, I create job as below:

```
* * * * * /usr/src/debug/http/cron_job.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

inside cron_job.sh as below

```
pidof html
if [ 0 = $? ]
then
 echo running
else 
 cd /usr/src/debug/http/
 ./html
fi
```

but when I check the running program it show that

```
2738 ? ... ./html
2748 ? ... ./html
2788 ? ... ./html
```

its seems duplicate it running the application, is there any wrong with my setting? kindly let me know how to solve this issued?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Redirecting any potential error messages to `/dev/null` does not help in troubleshooting

Comment: Hi, Can you rephrase your question? or clarify the objective? I think you are trying to check if a service is up or not via cron job and then start it if it is down? Have you tested your script outside cron to make sure it is working the way you wanted it to. Also there are other monitoring and reporting tools that can alert you about services (such as Nagios, Icinga). Maybe better to look at those.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [Prevent duplicate cron jobs running](https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running)

Answer (score 0):

Your cron job starts running with its current working directory set to the home directory of the user that owns the job. When you specify the script to be executed as `/usr/src/debug/http/cron_job.sh`, that does *not* cause the working directory to be changed.

So, the `pidof html` is effectively doing the same thing as `pidof $HOME/html`. Later in the script it is revealed that the `html` executable is actually in `/usr/src/debug/http/html`, so the `pidof html` command needs the full path to the executable you're testing, so replace it with:

```
pidof /usr/src/debug/http/html
```

If `/usr/src/debug/http/html` is actually a script, you'll also need to add the `-x` option:

```
pidof -x /usr/src/debug/http/html
```

Another way to fix the script would be to simply move the `cd /usr/src/debug/http` command to become the first line of the cron job script, so that the script will always change into the correct directory, before even trying to test for the existence of the `html` process.